# Excel VBA: For loop - Write value of row number

Tags: excel, vba

The way my code currently works is like this:

ws1 has multiple columns and rows of data. The first cell on every row in column A is the title. The titles are from a fixed selection (it's a drop down) which are determined by a list that is on ws2

ws2 has the list of titles, which is h3 until LastRow

ws3 I'm trying to set up a for loop so from A6 onwards it writes 1 row of data from ws1 of each title.

So if ws2 has 5 titles, then ws3 will write 5 lines of data, and the data comes from the EntireRow on ws1

Currently, my for loop will return the correct titles and the row numbers of the matched data (which I have verified using debug print)

What I can't seem to figure out is how to get it to write on ws3 a line for each match. In my last line I have `ws3.Range("A6:A15").EntireRow.Value = ws1.Range("A" & row_num2).EntireRow.Value` but this seems to print the last match on every row between A6 to A15 (so the same value on every row)

I feel like it's something to do with the placement of the code, as it doesn't seem to loop correctly. It's looping until the last line and then only returning the last line.

```
Sub CardsCollection()

Set ws1 = Sheets("Database")
Set ws2 = Sheets("Insert")
Set ws3 = Sheets("Sheet1")

Dim myCell As Range
Dim LastRow As Long

LastRow = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
Debug.Print LastRow

Dim test_string As String
test_string = "H" & LastRow
Dim test_range As Range
Set test_range = ws2.Range(test_string)

variable_condition = Range("C3")

For Each myCell In ws2.Range("H3" & ":" & test_string)
    Debug.Print myCell
    row_num2 = Evaluate("MATCH(1,('" & ws1.Name & "'!A:A=""" & myCell & """)*('" & ws1.Name & "'!F:F=""" & variable_condition & """),0)")
    Debug.Print row_num2
    ws3.Range("A6:A15").EntireRow.Value = ws1.Range("A" & row_num2).EntireRow.Value
Next

End Sub
```

Would appreciate any help! Thanks

Comment: `ws3.Range("A6:A15").EntireRow.Value` - this line is overwriting so only the last values will survive.

Comment: Hey @SJR, that's the conclusion I've come to as well but I can't seem to figure out how to stop it overwriting

Comment: Not sure I follow what you're doing. Why not just add a single line in each iteration of your loop?

Comment: Because the number of rows is not a set number, it can vary depending on how many titles have been inputted into ws2 and if they have corresponding matches on ws1

Comment: But how did you arrive at A6:A15 - what's the logic?

Comment: When I tried just A6, which is where I wanted it to start writing from (a6 onwards), it didn't work, so I tried a range (a6-a15)

Comment: I had a reply over at MrExcel where someone suggested `NxtRw = 9` (9 being the starting row) and `ws3.Range("A" & NxtRw).EntireRow.Value = ws1.Range("A" & row_num2).EntireRow.Value`  and finally `NxtRw = NxtRw + 1`  and this worked, thought I'd leave it here in case anyone had a similar issue